# Python printing floating point numbers from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am new to programming and hav a small issue.

I have a small bit of code I am trying to print out the results from. When I print it it gives me some numbers with many decimal places and some with only one. If I try to change the placeholder from 's' to 'd' or 'f' it tell me it must be a number not a list.

Is there anyway to get this to print the numbers with 2 decimal places?

Here is the code:

```
ftp = 230
zones = []

def zone(n): 
    return   ftp * n

multipliers = (.55,.56,.75,.76,.85,.86,.95,.96, 1.05, 1.06, 1.20, 1.21, 1.50,1.51)

for i in (multipliers):
   zones.append(zone(i))

format = ('%-*s%*s')
header_format = '%-*s%*s'
print '=' * 65
print header_format % (45, 'Zone', 10, 'Range')
print '-' * 65

print format % (45,'Active Recovery               Below ==>> ',10, zones[:1])
print format % (45,'Endurance',10, zones[1:3])
print format % (45,'Tempo',10, zones[3:5])
print format % (45,'Sweet Spot',10, zones[5:7])
print format % (45,'Threshhold',10, zones[7:9])
print format % (45,'VO2',10, zones[9:11])
print format % (45,'Anaerobic',10, zones[11:13])
print format % (45,'Neuromuscular                 Above ==>>',5, zones[12])
print '=' * 65
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to adjust your `format` string accordingly.

Right now, you have (with redundant parentheses, as you also have elsewhere, BTW):

```
format = ('%-*s%*s')
```

This format two strings with given widths and alignments -- so the lists of floats that you're getting as slices of `zones` will be "just stringified" with no control over formatting details.

Sometimes you're emitting a single float, sometimes two of them.  It's better to use two separate format strings for the two separate purposes.

So for a single float

```
format1 = '%-*s%*.2f'
```

and for two of them

```
format2 = '%-*s%*.2f%*.2f'
```

Now, edit your various `print` statements accordingly, e.g the last one would become

```
print format1 % (45,'Neuromuscular                 Above ==>>',5, zones[12])
```

and the one just before it

```
print format2 % (45,'Anaerobic',5,zones[11],5,zones[12])
```

(The parentheses here are **not** redundant as you need a tuple on the RHS of the `%` operator.

BTW, the new `format` method of strings can be much more readable than the old `%` formatting operator, and I would recommend switching to it...

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks!. I am currently looking into using the new format method. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can format the numbers separately from the rest of the string:

```
two_numbers_format = '(%.2f - %.2f)'
```

And then have:

```
print format % (45,'Endurance',10, two_numbers_format % zones[1:3])
```

And For one number:

```
one_number_format = '%.2f'
print format % (45,'Active Recovery               Below ==>> ',10, one_number_format % zones[:1])
```